# Site Design containing library with folders

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-template, site-design, site-script

I created a Site Script to create a site design, and the site script includes a document library with many folders in it.

The site design deploys without any problems, but when I try to apply it to the site, it errors:[image]

Is there actually a way to create a site template that comes prepopulated with libraries that has folders? Copying my site script below.

```
    {
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/site-design-script-actions.schema.json",
  "actions": [
    {
      "verb": "createSPList",
      "listName": "Documents",
      "templateType": 101,
      "subactions": [
        {
          "verb": "addFolder",
          "path": "Application"
        
        }

      ]
    } 
  ],
  "version": 1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Per my research, there is no "add folder" subaction when we create a new SharePoint list using JSON schema.

For more information,please refer to:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-design-json-schema

Comment: There's actually a add folder subaction but I don't think it's yet been enabled?

I just found out that you can add "Triggerflow" action and the action would create folders. So will go ahead with that as a workaround- if it works!